# Flutter - Update your app so that the feature uses MediaStore APIs and remove All files access (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission. FLUTTER

Tags: android, flutter

I have added this in Manifiest:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

But app is rejected by Google. I got this reason:-

[image]

Comment: And?  I mean, what's your question.  Follow their rules. :)

Comment: @RandalSchwartz My question is that, I need Storage permision that is why I have to use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. but due to this permission Google is rejecting the app. Could you please help to fix this?

Comment: Again, explain to me in simple terms why you need arbitrary access to my files?

Comment: Actually I want to create directories in device storage for storing the multimedia as Whatsapp and Telegram do.

Answer (score 1):

Because of Android version 12 , you face this issue as Google restrict some policy regarding storage,

You can use below package for Storage Framework Access , With this usage your app won't rejected.

[SAF](https://pub.dev/packages/saf)

Comment: Hi @Kevin Devani, https://pub.dev/packages/saf this package do not provide feature to create directory. Actually I want to create directories for storing the multimedia as Whatsapp and Telegram do.